# What is pgettext_lazy in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I was working with an open-source project (made in Django). I couldn't understand what `pgettext_lazy` is used for. Can you please tell me

1. What is pgettext_lazy?
2. Usage of pgettext_lazy?

Answer (score 13):

[**`pgettext_lazy(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/) is a function that is used to *translate* text. The Django documentation has a [section on *translation* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/) that discusses this.

`pgettext_lazy` is a lazy variant of `pgettext`. This is a function that makes [context-aware translations [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#contextual-markers). Context-aware translations deal with the fact that a word can be translated in multiple ways. For example `May` can be translated as the name of a month, or a verb.

We can make it clear how to translate it by adding a "context marker", and thus call the translation with:

> ```
> from django.utils.translation import pgettext
>
> month = pgettext("month name", "May")
> ```

In your `.po` file(s), the files you use to define translations, you can then add the context marker:

```
msgctxt "month name"
msgid "May"
msgstr ""
```

You can make translations in the views in the language that is activated, but you can not just define that translation in for example the `help_text` of a model. Indeed, if you would call `pgettext(..)` in a `models.py` file. It would translate the `help_text` in the language that is active at that time. But if later a user with a different language uses that `help_text`, it would not be translated in the other language.

By making the translation *lazy*, the process of translation is *postponed* until a `str(..)` is called on the result. That way, if you render the lazy object in a template it will be translated in the language of the user.

You can find more information on this in the [*Translation* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/).

Comment: @MayankBudhiraja: if this is satisfyingly answering your question, feel free to accept it (green tick) so other users know there is a correct answer.